# Can't send a multipart request using Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, angular-reactive-forms

My Java backend API is expecting a multipart POST request for a form on the Angular frontend, which is currently using reactive forms. The endpoint looks like this:

```
  @PostMapping("/submit")
  public ResponseEntity<?> submit(
      @RequestParam String requester,
      @RequestParam String subject,
      @RequestParam String description,
      @RequestParam String htmlBody,
      @RequestParam String customFieldValues,
      @RequestParam List<MultipartFile> attachments) {

    return myBackendService.submitToZendesk(
        requester, subject, description, htmlBody, customFieldValues, attachments);
  }
```

The submit functionality in the Angular component looks like this (currently using fake form data):

```
  public onSubmit(): void {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('requester', 'ryan');
    formData.append('subject', 'Test Subject',);
    formData.append('description', 'test desc',);
    formData.append('htmlBody', '',);
    formData.append('customFieldValues', 'test');
    this.frontendService.submitForm(formData).subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => this.onHandleError(err)
    );
  }
```

The service:

```
  public submitForm(payload: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.resourceService.submitForm(payload)
  }
```

And then lastly, the resource service:

```
  public submitShippingAuth(payload: ShippingAuthRequest): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${environment.api}/submit`
    return this.http.post(`${url}`, payload)
      .pipe(map(this.extractResponse), catchError(this.handleError))
  }
```

I get a 400 status code with the post:

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "Required String parameter 'requester' is not present"
path: "/v1/submit"
status: 400
timestamp: 1571771034002
trace: "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'requester' is not present
```

But my request payload certainly seems to have the form-data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTIuEnyoDjbqZHnFA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requester"

ryan
------WebKitFormBoundaryTIuEnyoDjbqZHnFA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Test Subject
------WebKitFormBoundaryTIuEnyoDjbqZHnFA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

test desc
------WebKitFormBoundaryTIuEnyoDjbqZHnFA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="htmlBody"


------WebKitFormBoundaryTIuEnyoDjbqZHnFA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customFieldValues"

test
------WebKitFormBoundaryTIuEnyoDjbqZHnFA--
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? The form-data POST in Postman works.

Answer (score 0):

The line to print requester should contain comma(,) like below
formData.append('requester', 'ryan', );

Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sapna. Unfortunately, this did not fix it. Is there a reason why the extra comma has to be there or were you just pointing out an inconsistency? As far as I know the third arg of `formData.append` is just for a filename, so it isn't necessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

The submit functionality surely looks fine, the third arg in `formData.append` is the filename so it isn't necessary. The only thing i found is that u have not set headers in the `http post` request. I am guessing that you are using `interceptors` to do so, if not please try doing it.